# expire wordpress posts in the query - not the loop

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently using the following code to expire and hide posts after my custom field 'date' in the loop (which works fine):

```
<?php
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
//to check against expiration date;
$currentdate = date("Ymd");
$expirationdate = get_post_custom_values('date');
if (is_null($expirationdate)) {
$expirestring = '30005050'; //MAKE UN-EXPIRING POSTS ALWAYS SHOW UP;
} else {
if (is_array($expirationdate)) {
$expirestringarray = implode($expirationdate);
}
$expirestring = str_replace("/","",$expirestringarray);
} //else
if ( $expirestring >= $currentdate ) { 
// post loop contents
} ?>
```

I would like to filter out the posts in the query instead - is this possible. I have a plugin that generates a google map from the results of the query, not the loop - anyone got any ideas? here's my current query

```
<?php query_posts($query_string.'&order=asc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=date');
if (have_posts()) : ?>
```

I forgot to mention that the resulting posts should also be sorted by the same date field appearing with the closest date to now first.

Comment: @Sterex very frustrating that I can't comment on your answer yet!! Anyway - I'm afk at the moment - well my work keyboard anyway... but first thoughts are: 
1) will this properly push the query into the plugin? Basically I'm using the mappress plugin on the page - it picks up the query from the page, you can put some custom elements but the only way I can see to filter expired posts is to do it at query level 
2) can I use this to load the entirety of the page, including custom fields - not just the title?
thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. To push the query into the plugin, you can replace the wordpress loop in the theme page to your own as described in my answer. You can do it at the post level also. For each post, check the expiration date, and skip showing that post if it is expired. While this may seem easy, it is cumbersome and you will not have control on the order of the posts. 2. Oh yes. I just showed that as an example. You can use it to load all the post details. :-)

Comment: @Sterex - Ok, I should have added thatposts appearing in revers chronological sort by the date field is imperitive!!! Its for an events page. My mistake I should have put that in the original question

Comment: Then, simply remove the `wpostmeta.meta_value DESC` from the `ORDER BY` in the code below. That way, your posts will be retrieved in reverse chronological order of post date and it will get posts whose expiration date is less than current date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

 $querystr = "
    SELECT wposts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
    AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'date' 
    AND wpostmeta.meta_value < CURRENT_DATE
    AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND wposts.post_type = 'post' 
    ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC, wpostmeta.meta_value DESC
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

 ?>
```

I'm assuming that the meta-value for the meta-key 'date' is stored in the mysql format ('YYYY-MM-DD'). If not, you may try using the [mysql date time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) to format it accordingly.

You can then use the following code to display the posts.

```
 <?php if ($pageposts): ?>
 <?php global $post; ?>
 <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
 <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
 <h2><?php echo $post->title; ?></h2>
 <?php endif; ?>
```